# Single sign-on TicketValidationException

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I create a server and client, the client is not configure virtual directory "/ EIP", can be used normally; If configured with a virtual directory will appear the following questions:

server error message

```
 ERROR org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl
-ServiceTicket ST-11-SLvleOutvxi7VEy53Q07-cas01.example.org with service 
http://localhost:9999/eip/eip/ 
does not match supplied service 
http://localhost:9999/eip/eip/eip/
```

Client error message

```
2014-01-25 15:52:56,799 WARN [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter] - 
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: 
        XXX'ST-2-KORiek3rHflhLctqzGT5-cas01.example.org'XXXXXXXX    
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator.parseResponseFromServer(Cas20ServiceTicketValidator.java:86)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:217)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I use the service side is：cas-server-3.5.2，
The following is my configuration of this file：deployerConfigContext.xml

```
>   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
>        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
>        xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
>        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
>        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
>    CentralAuthenticationService service bean         | declared in
> applicationContext.xml picks up this AuthenticationManager by
> reference to its id,          | "authenticationManager".  Most deployers
> will be able to use the default AuthenticationManager         |
> implementation and so do not need to change the class of this bean. 
> We include the whole      | AuthenticationManager here in the
> userConfigContext.xml so that you can see the things you will         | need
> to change in context.         +-->           class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">
>                           This switch effectively will turn on clearpass.        
>          
>             
>                
>             
>                          -->
>                AuthenticationManagerImpl considers them in order, finding a
> CredentialToPrincipalResolver which           | supports the presented
> credentials.          |           | AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers
> for two purposes.  First, it uses them to identify the Principal          |
> attempting to authenticate to CAS /login .  In the default
> configuration, it is the DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver            |
> that fills this role.  If you are using some other kind of credentials
> than UsernamePasswordCredentials, you will need to replace            |
> DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver with a
> CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the credentials you are
>           | using.            |           | Second, AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these
> resolvers to identify a service requesting a proxy granting ticket. 
>           | In the default configuration, it is the
> HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver that serves this
> purpose.              | You will need to change this list if you are
> identifying services by something more or other than their callback
> URL.          +-->        
>           
>                                  | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials that we use for /login 
>                   | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying the username from the credentials.
>                   | 
>                   | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also
>                   | need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that
> supports the
>                   | Credentials you are using.
>                   +-->
>                >
>                   
>               
>                                  | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.  It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of
>                   | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a
>                   | SimpleService identified by that callback URL.
>                   |
>                   | If you are representing services by something more or other than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to
>                   | receive a proxy callback, you will need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations).
>                   +-->
>                                  class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver"
> />                     
> 
>        some Credentials might authenticate,              | AuthenticationHandlers
> actually authenticate credentials.  Here we declare the
> AuthenticationHandlers that           | authenticate the Principals that the
> CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identified.  CAS will try these
> handlers in turn          | until it finds one that both supports the
> Credentials presented and succeeds in authenticating.             +-->
>                   
>                                  | This is the authentication handler that authenticates services by means of callback via SSL, thereby validating
>                   | a server side SSL certificate.
>                   +-->
>                                  p:httpClient-ref="httpClient"/>
>                                  | This is the authentication handler declaration that every CAS deployer will need to change before deploying CAS 
>                   | into production.  The default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler authenticates
> UsernamePasswordCredentials
>                   | where the username equals the password.  You will need to replace this with an AuthenticationHandler that implements your
>                   | local authentication strategy.  You might accomplish this by coding a new such handler and declaring
>                   | edu.someschool.its.cas.MySpecialHandler here, or you might use one of the handlers provided in the adaptors modules.
>                   +-->
>                   
>                    
>                                              value="select password from a_user where lower(userName) = lower(?)" />
>                   
>                                
>                                  class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler"
> />
>                   -->                           
> 
> 
>    Management application.  Simple deployments can use the in-memory
> version.  More robust deployments will want to use another option,
> such as the Jdbc version.         The name of this should remain
> "userDetailsService" in order for Spring Security to find it.      -->
>     -->
> 
>     
>         
>             A real implementation     may go against a database or LDAP server.  The
> id should remain "attributeRepository" though.     -->      id="attributeRepository"
>       class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
>                   
>               
>                
>                                             -->     class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao"
> id="attributeRepository">
>         
>        
>         
>             
>                 
>             
>         
>         
>             
>                 
>                 
>             
>                      replace this with the JPA-backed ServiceRegistry DAO  The name of this
> bean should remain "serviceRegistryDao".   -->           id="serviceRegistryDao"
>         class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
>             
>                 
>                     
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                                 
>                                         id
>                                         username
>                                         idcard
>                                         phone
>                                 
>                         
>                     
>                                          Use the following definition instead of the above to further restrict access
>                     to services within your domain (including subdomains).
>                     Note that example.com must be replaced with the domain you wish to permit.
>                     -->
>                                          
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                         
>                     
>                     -->
>                 
>             
>         
> 
>    class="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"
> />
>      
>     
>       
>                      p:freeMemoryWarnThreshold="10" />
>                    NOTE
>           The following ticket registries support SessionMonitor:
>             * DefaultTicketRegistry
>             * JpaTicketRegistry
>           Remove this monitor if you use an unsupported registry.
>         -->
>                      p:ticketRegistry-ref="ticketRegistry"
>             p:serviceTicketCountWarnThreshold="5000"
>             p:sessionCountWarnThreshold="100000" />
>       
>           
>     
>      
>           oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>      
>      
>        jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.124.32.56:1521:orcl -->
>            jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.13:1522:SERVER10  
>            jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1522:work-->
>      
>      
>           gzedieip
>      
>      
>           gzkit
>       
> 
>
```

Who know what the reason, thank you

Comment: We can not diagnose the problem without seeing the code that is causing the problem. Please post `AuthenticationSunitFilter.java` line `135` and relevant contextual information.

Comment: Thank you very much to answer my question，‘AuthenticationSunitFilter’' 'is my rewrite the class，I to the original class：<pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: 
  XXXXXXX 'ST-12-xvSwYT1ImDPtZ9QEQAEJ-cas01.example.org'XXXXXX
 
 org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:194)
 org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:116)
</pre>

Comment: Nope, nope, nope. Up thar ^ is an edit button. Click it, and make your changes please. That appears to be a stacktrace, not actual code.

Comment: I changed as you said，I think it should be the server configuration is wrong；

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem is that the client configuration,Regardless of the program has no virtual directory,  the client configuration is no need to add a virtual directory